# Gun freezes up after one shot then does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine

My gun will freeze up after one shot and there are no errors.

I'm still working on it so no ammo and stuff. I am using https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/props/guns/modern-guns-handgun-129821
as a base model width no code the code is mine.

Here are the settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3feNw.png

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header ("Ammo Settings")]
    public string ReloadTriggerName = "Reload";
    public int ReloadTime;
    public int ClipSize;
    public int MaxAmmo;
    private int CurrentAmmo;
    public KeyCode ReloadKey = KeyCode.R;

    [Header ("Aim Settings")]
    public KeyCode Aimkey = KeyCode.Mouse1;
    public int TimeToAim;
    public Transform Anchor;
    public Transform Aim;
    public Transform hip;
    [Header ("Mis")]
    public Animator animator;
    public bool IsAutomatic;
    public int coolDown;

    [Header("basic setting")]
    public string FireTriggerName = "Fire";
    public int Damage = 10;
    public Transform gunTip; 

    //Script vars
    private bool CanFire = true;
    private bool Reloading = false;

    void Start()
    {
        CurrentAmmo = ClipSize;
    }
    void Update()
    {
       if(CanFire)
       {
        if(IsAutomatic)
        {
            if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && !Reloading && CurrentAmmo > 0) 
            {
                Shoot();
                CanFire = false;
                Invoke("ResetCanShoot", coolDown);
            } 
        } else
        {
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !Reloading && CurrentAmmo > 0) 
            {
                Shoot();
                CanFire = false;
                Invoke("ResetCanShoot", coolDown);
            }
        }

        AimGun(Input.GetKey(Aimkey));

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(ReloadKey) && CurrentAmmo > ClipSize)
        {
            
        }

        }
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger(FireTriggerName);
         CurrentAmmo = CurrentAmmo - 1;

         //Shoot
         print("Pew");
         RaycastHit hit;
         if (Physics.Raycast(gunTip.position, gunTip.transform.forward, out hit))
         {
            
             Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

             ZombieHealth zombieHealth = hit.transform.GetComponent<ZombieHealth>();
             if(zombieHealth != null)
             {
                 zombieHealth.TakeDamage(Damage);
             }
         }
    }

    void AimGun(bool isAiming)
    {
        if(isAiming)
        {
            Anchor.position = Vector3.Lerp(Anchor.position, Aim.position, Time.deltaTime * TimeToAim);
        } else
        {
            Anchor.position = Vector3.Lerp(Anchor.position, hip.position, Time.deltaTime * TimeToAim);
        }
    }



    void ResetCanShoot()
    {
        CanFire = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should probably rather be

```
void ResetCanShoot()
{
    CanFire = true;
}
```

otherwise you are never allowing a next shoot.

Comment: Thx man I found that out just now on my own I did not think someone will respond so quick but yeah I was just going to the remove the post don't the code i worked really Hard on them and there not done going to plan to relese them some public when im dove

Comment: BTW if i publish this i will give you a free version of it for helping me